# Stop indefinite loop of files through directory

Tags: bash

I would like to loop through files in a directory that match a particular filename pattern. At the moment, I am using the following piece of code as a point of reference:

```
shopt -s nullglob
while :; do
  files=("/home/methuselah"/${filePattern})
  if [ ${#files} -gt 0 ]; then
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    # something to be done here
    done
  fi
done
```

The issue with this is that it will loop indefinitely. I want it to stop as soon as its gone through the files available in the directory. How do I impose this restriction?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify it to just the inner loop.

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( /home/methuselah/$filePattern )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    # something to be done here
done
```

Comment: No need for them at all then.